# xor the two numbers in place swap?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

I came across a question with swapping two numbers using xor. so the it's basically `x=x^y; y=x^y; x=x^y`, and i can think of `y=(x^y)^y=x`,so that y now becomes x, but on the last one wouldn't it be`x=x^y = (x^y)^(x^y)= 0?` how does x become y?

Comment: It wouldn't be that, no.

Comment: Suggestion: try running the algorithm by hand using x=123 and y=82 or some other concrete values. Then you can see if your assumptions about if and why the algorithm doesn't work are true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=x^y
y=(x^y)^y
x=(x^y)^((x^y)^y) //here is how you get x = y
```

you did the substitution wrong.